# 'いつ空いていますか' vs 'いつ空きますか'

Tags: て-form

What's the difference between the two?

According to some machine translation, it is:

```
いつ空いていますか
When are you free

いつ空きますか 
When will you be free
```

Is that as accurate?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is that as accurate?

It actually is, roughly speaking.

Here is the real difference in meaning and usage.

> 「いつ空いていますか。」

asks about when (what days of the week, what time, etc.) the other person tends to be (relatively) free.  Thus, this question would generally be replied to with:

・「火曜日と木曜日の午前中。」

・「月水金の午後４時以降。」, etc.

> 「いつ空きますか。」

is quite different in that it can be asked **only when the other person is occupied** and you want to find out about around what time the other person will have some free time for you.  Therefore, this question would often be replied to with:

・「あと１時間くらいかなぁ。」

・「３時頃なら時間あるわよ。」, etc.